# How to get Wordpad or Microsoft Word 2010 ribbon's icons?

Tags: get, ms-word, icons, ribbon, wordpad

I'm using Windows 8 and Microsoft Office 2010.
Can you help me how to get Wordpad or Microsoft Word 2010 ribbon's icons (bold, italic icons,...) as standalone image?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for a path where the images are stored?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the standalone images of MS Office 2010 use the link:

http://www.iconarchive.com/tag/office-ribbon

and download the respective icon